# XML Preview with resources in other modules

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, module

I recently moved all my resources from my app module to a different submodule.
Everything works as expected, build is successful, on the phone as well.

However in the XML preview pane, all layouts in the app module give me "Rendering Problems Couldn't resolve resource " in the preview pane, when I try to reference any resource (like a color value for a textview) which is located in other modules (although the submodule was added as a dependency and works well when compiled and run)

Comment: Why have you made different module for keeping resources?

Comment: My app uses other modules, let's say there's a submodule only for a specific task, like showing alerts. This submodule however needs to use the same theme as the main app. So to be able to share the resources between modules, I created a module only for that, that way all modules can reference them. Doesn't work another way because if i put resources in main app module, submodules can't see them since they don't have the main app as dependency (only main app has the submodules as dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by deleting the build folder, deleting *.iml and idea/, then re-importing the project!